# MongoDB: Not enough nodes match write concern mode

Tags: node.js, mongodb, replicaset

Following mongodb insert operation gives an error:

```
db.dumpset.insert( { id: "xyz", status: "A" }, { writeConcern: { w: "activeNodes" } } )

WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 1,
    "writeConcernError" : {
        "code" : 100,
        "errmsg" : "Not enough nodes match write concern mode \"activeNodes\""
    }
})
```

There are 3 nodes in replica set tagged with `production` and the custom writeConcern looks like below:

```
"getLastErrorModes" : {
            "activeNodes" : {
                "production" : 3
            }
        }
```

MongoDB version 3.2.11, is there anything missing?

Comment: Have you double-checked the status of the replica set and of all the nodes?

Comment: yes..they're all up and healthy

Comment: Can you show the output from rs.status(), in case there are any clues in there?